# Browser is opening in mobile mode when running selenium tests via jenkins on linux server

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am executing Selenium tests via jenkins on a linux machine, i am able to run scripts on Firefox browser using xvfb plugin but browser is rendering in mobile mode rather than desktop mode(some menus are changing ex: Facet Search) so some scripts are failing. I tried by changing user agent using FF profile but dint work. Please help me to run scripts in normal/desktop mode.

Comment: do you want to change the browser size?

Comment: Hi Sudharsan, thanks for responding. We have changed resolution in linux server but still dint work. Not sure if it works if we change browser size..i will try..can u provide the code to change browser size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before changing browser resolution, you need to set the screen size of XVFB buffer.

if you are using XVFB jenkins plugin, refer [How to change XVFB screen size in jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin)

if your running using `xvfb-run` command, then try the below command while starting a process under XVFB,

```
xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 2920x2580x24"
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sudharsan. Its working perfectly now.